# Polish locales in Angular 4+

Tags: angular, locale

I'm trying to set static locales of my angular 6 project. After changing everything correctly to the documentation it is still displaying en-US locales.

**main.ts**

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePl from '@angular/common/locales/pl';

registerLocaleData(localePl);
...
providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pl' }
  ],
```

**.html**

```
<div>
  <h2>
    Razem do zapłaty:<span>{{ toPay | currency }}</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

**Image of not translated text**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Please follow this link.

Comment: My locales are working, currency not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the correct locale for polish, but you will need to use it in such a manner like this:-

```
<div>
      <h2>
        Razem do zapłaty:<span>{{ toPay | currency:'PLN': true }}</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
```

Please try this hope this works

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup default currency: `PLN`. Here is example:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePl from '@angular/common/locales/pl';

registerLocaleData(localePl);
...
providers: 
[
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pl' },
    { provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, useValue: 'PLN' }
],
```